# Ошибка при рисовании русского текста в Pillow: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

При работе с библиотекой PIL(pillow) я столкнулся с ошибкой из-за русских слов. Можно ли эту проблему как-то решить?

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 233, in text
    mask, offset = font.getmask2(text, self.fontmode)

AttributeError: 'ImageFont' object has no attribute 'getmask2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "maker_schedule_png.py", line 58, in <module>
draw.text(position,temp_str)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 237, in text
mask = font.getmask(text, self.fontmode)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 3-5: ordinal not in range(256)
```

p.s. Вот код:

```
import json
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
list_day_of_week = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']

with open('schedule.json','r') as file_schedule:
    schedule = json.loads(file_schedule.read())
    file_schedule.close()

with open('lessons.json','r') as file_lessons:
    lessons = json.loads(file_lessons.read())
    file_lessons.close()

list_need = []
for i in list_day_of_week:
    if schedule[i] != {}:
        list_need.append(i)

list_number_lessons = []
for day_of_week in list_need:
    for day in schedule[day_of_week]:
        for number in day:
            if not(number in list_number_lessons):
                list_number_lessons.append(number)
list_number_lessons = sorted(list_number_lessons)

size = ((len(list_need))*200, (len(list_number_lessons))*60)

image = Image.new("RGB", size, (0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
index_y = 0
index_x = 0

for index_1 in list_need:
    for index_2 in list_number_lessons:
        temp_str = '{}. '.format(index_2)
        if index_2 in schedule[index_1]:
            symbol_two_lessons = schedule[index_1][index_2].find('/')
            if symbol_two_lessons == -1:
                lessons_1 = schedule[index_1][index_2]
                lessons_1 = lessons[lessons_1]['full']
                temp_str += lessons_1
            else:
                lessons_1 = schedule[index_1][index_2][:symbol_two_lessons]
                lessons_2 = schedule[index_1][index_2][symbol_two_lessons+1:]

                lessons_1 = lessons[lessons_1]['briefly']
                lessons_2 = lessons[lessons_2]['briefly']

                temp_str += lessons_1
                temp_str += '/'
                temp_str += lessons_2
        print(temp_str)
        temp_str.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')
        position = [index_x, index_y, index_x + 200, index_y + 60]
        draw.rectangle(position)
        position = [index_x, index_y + 30]
        draw.text(position,temp_str)
        index_y += 60
    index_y = 0
    index_x += 200
```

Comment: Давайте ваш код, демонстрирующий проблему

Comment: @andreymal добавил код

Comment: Как минимум у вас строчка `temp_str.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')` ничего не делает, потому что вы результат вызова метода никуда не сохраняете

Comment: @andreymal я исправил и всё заработало, но дело в том я хотел в изображение вставить текст русские буквы, а так как я сделал `ignore` у меня остались только точки в некоторых сокращениях.

Comment: Вообще это как-то странно, когда я в своих программах делал draw.text, всё прекрасно работало и русский текст выводился, пока не понимаю почему у вас не работает. Но на всякий случай - пробовали установить самую последнюю версию Pillow?

Comment: @andreymal pip выдал `Pillow (4.0.0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте параметр *encoding='UTF-8'* при загрузке шрифта:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
img = Image.new('RGB', (1000,500))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
str = 'Привет'
font = ImageFont.truetype("Roboto-Regular.ttf", 32, encoding='UTF-8')
# draw.text((10, 10), str) -- ошибка
draw.text((10, 10), str, font=font)
img.save('test.jpg')
```

Pillow (5.2.0)